# SQL execute random name

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In SQL, how are you going to select 1 of the 5 random name every time the query executes? for example, given that the names are `'Joey', 'John', 'Jay', 'George', 'Greg'`

Answer (score 4):

The traditional way to get a random row from a table in SQL Server is:

```
select top 1 name
from names
order by newid();
```